# How to bind a report to a DataSource and send it to the ReportViewer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-reporting

I am trying to build a reporting system using the Telerik reporting framework. So far I've been able to use the vs designer to create reports but haven't managed to get the attached to any kind of dynamic data.

I am doing this in an ASP.NET MVC project (not a telerik MVC project. Does it matter?).

I currently have:

1. The controller that was created automatically when using the reportviewer wizard
2. The report
3. A Model I want to use for populating the report

Here is the code in my view:

```
@model Telerik.Reporting.ReportSource

@(Html.TelerikReporting().ReportViewer()
        .Id("reportViewer1")
        .ServiceUrl(Url.Content("~/api/reports"))
        .ReportSource(model)
        .ViewMode(ViewMode.Interactive)
        .ScaleMode(ScaleMode.Specific)
        .Scale(1.0)
        .PersistSession(false)
        .PrintMode(PrintMode.AutoSelect)
)
```

One thing that immediately confused me is how can I define what data to fetch?

Say I have a model that I want to use for populating the report:

```
public class ReportModel()
{
    Dictionary<string, int> Graphdata;

    public ReportModel()
    {
         Graphdata = GetGraphData();
    }

    public Dictionary<string, int> GetGraphData()
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

So in the Reports controller I would create a new report:

```
var report = new Report1();
```

Now I have to create the datasource for the report. This is where I'm stuck...

The model for the report would contain multiple lists, tables, dictionaries for all of the different elements in the report.

In the documentation, they do this:

```
// Creating and configuring the ObjectDataSource component:
var objectDataSource = new Telerik.Reporting.ObjectDataSource();
objectDataSource.DataSource = typeof(Products); // Specifying the business object type
objectDataSource.DataMember = "GetProducts"; // Specifying the name of the data object method
objectDataSource.CalculatedFields.Add(new Telerik.Reporting.CalculatedField("FullName", typeof(string), "=Fields.Name + ' ' + Fields.ProductNumber")); // Adding a sample calculated field.

// Specify the parameters, their types and values
objectDataSource.Parameters.Add(new Telerik.Reporting.ObjectDataSourceParameter("color", typeof(string), "Silver"));
objectDataSource.Parameters.Add(new Telerik.Reporting.ObjectDataSourceParameter("productModelID", typeof(int), 23));
```

And that's where I get lost. So here are my questions:

If I have multiple elements on a report, do I have to create a datasource for each of them?

What is the proper MVC way to bind data to a report?

If the reportviewer is getting the actual report via an API, how does the api know to send it the data that was bound when the report object was created?

Answer (score 0):

> I am doing this in an ASP.NET MVC project (not a telerik MVC project.
>   Does it matter?).

No, it should make no difference. The telerik MVC project just does some of the initial setup and dll references for you.

> One thing that immediately confused me is how can I define what data
>   to fetch?

The best ways to do this is either define the data at design time and bind it using the data explorer or data source wizard or alternatively by using the NeedDataSource event of the report to build the data through some other means at run time.

References:

- http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/data-items-binding-a-data-item-to-data
- http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/data-items-need-data-source-event

> If I have multiple elements on a report, do I have to create a
>   datasource for each of them?

This depends on a lot of things...What do you mean by "element"? - most things will NOT need a separate data source.  Some subreports maybe better designed using separate datasources, but even that's not necessary most of the time if you are able to pass the data source from the parent report to the subreport.

Reference:  http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/data-items-binding-a-data-item-to-data#binding-to-data-from-the-parent-data-item

> What is the proper MVC way to bind data to a report?

Either by binding the data at design time using the data explorer or by using the Rerport's NeedDataSource to generate the data at run time as explained above. Either option can support parameters to allow you to construct "dynamic" data for your report based on input variables from the report viewer.

> If the reportviewer is getting the actual report via an API, how does the api know to send it the data that was bound when the report object was created?

The report viewer is responsible for loading a report.  The report should be responsible for fetching and binding its own data.